# SPARQL why are there both DELETE and WHERE conditions?

Tags: rdf, sparql, triplestore

Recently I was deleting some data according to a matching pattern `?s a :answers` and I notices that I could only get the deletion to correctly proceed if I had both condition blocks as the same:

```
PREFIX :      <http://localhost:2020/vocab/> 
DELETE {
    ?s a :answers
}
WHERE {
    ?s a :answers
}
# returns all the correct data
```

and if the delete block is more generalized, nothing is returned:

```
PREFIX :      <http://localhost:2020/vocab/>
DELETE {
    ?s ?p ?o
}
WHERE {
    ?s a :answers
}
# returns 0 rows
```

What is the purpose of having two different sets of conditions (the stuff between curly braces: `{...}` )? and which one actually selects the data to be deleted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because what you delete may not be what you match with WHERE.

There is a special form for the first case:

```
DELETE WHERE { ?s a :answers }
```

In the second, ?p and ?o are not bound. Try:

```
DELETE {
    ?s ?p ?o
}
WHERE {
    ?s a :answers .
    ?s ?p ?o .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the `WHERE` clause you can just use `DELETE DATA`. That has no WHERE clause and just deletes whatever patterns you have in the fist clause. The reason you might want to use `DELETE ... WHERE ...` is that the WHERE clause gives you more power to specify only deleting certain triples. E.g., in your example, you might not want to delete the entire graph but instead you might want to delete all triples that have an instance of :answers as the subject. That is what that query should do. If you do: `DELETE DATA {?s ?p ?o}` that should remove the entire graph.